# Responsive/Adaptive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Just want to start by thanking you for viewing this post.

I am currently trying to get some experience with html, CSS and JavaScript so I can try to get my foot in the Front End Developer field. I have been working on this adaptive design today but a few issue's have came up. Here is the following problems:

I am not able to get the right DIV to stay on the same line as the left DIV when I re-size the screen. Along the road I will add media rules to make the size even more responsive for the phone/tablet user's.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 14px/24px"Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.contentcontainer {
  width: 100%;
}
#header,
#nav {
  border-radius: 23px;
}
#header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
#header {
  background: #2db34a;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#nav {
  background: #008e7b;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#nav h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#left,
#middle,
#right {
  border-radius: 23px;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  background: #7DC242;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#middle {
  float: left;
  width: 75.5%;
  background: #F68A1F;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#middle h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 55px;
}
#left h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 55px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <h2>Navigation</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentcontainer">
    <div id="left">
      <h1>Left</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <h1>Middle</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also as you can see there is probably some repetitive items and just some unnecessary items in my code if you could give me some tips on how to make my code smaller and load faster that would also be amazing!

Thank you! :)
-Neiko Anglin

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a responsive row of divs, i would really reccommend to **not** use margin, but padding. at least for left and right. Why? I'll explain.

When you use margin, you have to do calculations (using css calc() ) to make it work properly.
This is because, if you set the column width, the margin isn't included, and the column is actually wider --> **it won't fit**

When you use padding in combination with `box-sizing: border-box`, the columns  are is still splitted up (except for their backgrounds), but the width of the columns is not wider than you have defined in your css (because of the border-box). --> **the columns do fit and it really makes your life easier.**

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/n0acjahj/